Connection with presto cluster using R
I am trying to establish a connection with Presto CLuster, but I am receiving the following error message:

Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle) :
Could not resolve host: host_name

Code
library(odbc)
library(DBI)
library(RPresto)

user = "######"
passwd = "########"
cert_path <- "##########"

# Establish connection to Presto cluster
conn <- dbConnect(
  drv = RPresto::Presto(),
  host = "########",
  port = ####,
  user = user,
  catalog = "#######",
  schema = "########",
  requests_kwargs = list(
    auth = RPresto::HTTPBasicAuth(user, passwd),
    verify = TRUE,
    ca_path = cert_path
  )
)

# Execute SQL query
db <- dbGetQuery(
  conn, 
  "SELECT * FROM #####"
)

# Close the connection
dbDisconnect(conn)

